# Enter Reporting Services from another machine

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, report, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm new in SSRS and don't know how to get access to report from another machine than localhost.

I've created project via BIDS, deployed it and enter localhost/ReportServer/

But how can other people from local network get access to this report?

Comment: shows err_connection_refused error when trying MyServerName/ReportServer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You type in the name of the server, of IP address in the address bar.

eg. `http://192.168.1.1/ReportServer`

or

`http://MyServerName/ReportServer`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you didn't use Reporting Services at all. Instead, you are viewing reports from your development machine, right?

Now, you have 2 options:

1. Install Report Services on the server, or
2. Use MS Report Viewer (in this case, you have to install [MS Report Viewer Redist.Package](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6442)).

In any case, you need one machine to act as a server.

UPDATE: Oh, I see that you wrote: "localhost/ReportServer/" - so you have SSRS up-and-running. But do you want SSRS really runs on your local machine or you plan to deploy on real, production server?